# Set up audio streams in react-player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, react-player

I'm integrating the react-player component (https://github.com/CookPete/react-player) into my website, however, I don't find how could I set multiple audio streams.
Furthermore, I'd like to set both DASH and HLS video streams, but adding them as an array in url property is not working, how should I set the player's configuration?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can't define multiple streams in the configuration.

But you can use `this.setState({url: urlOfMyStream})` in the player load function to switch between the streams.

I hope, it can help.